# Google Geocoding API region biasing and city biasing

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get coordinates from address. But there are 6 places with same address. How can I set city biasing to find place in my city?
My request: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ul.+Stawki+2&sensor=false&region=pl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add city to the search string:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?  
   address=Warsaw,ul.%20Stawki%202&sensor=false&region=pl
```